# Non-lazy/short-circuited bool operators, force both arguments to evaluate

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Non-Short circuited logical “and” in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758608/is-there-an-non-short-circuited-logical-and-in-c)

I'm looking for a simple way to force the right side of a boolean expression (`||`  `&&`) to evaluate. Normally the right side is not evaluated if the left side can already determine the outcome.

Usually I revert to this syntax:

```
c = expr();
r = r || c;
```

since the following doesn't guarantee `expr()` will be evaluated:

```
r = r || expr();
```

Is there a shorter/simpler syntax to replace what I'm doing now? Or do I already have the most compact form?

*Tagged as C and C++ since the solution might be shared. I actually code in C++*

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758608/is-there-an-non-short-circuited-logical-and-in-c

Comment: @lesmana, agreed duplicate, I didn't find that when searching. It didn't include C, but would has the same answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this, firstly just evaluate both options and store the results as bools:

```
const bool a = expr();
const bool b = r;
return a || b;
```

Or you can use a function like so:

```
bool or(bool param1, bool param2)
{
    return param1 || param2;
}
```

and using the function will force both parameters to be evaluated before it is called.

Granted usually most people like the short circuit evaluation of boolean operators.

Answer (score 1):

In Java a single pipe or ampersand will work for non short-circuit evaluation for `boolean` types, but in C as you don't have a boolean data type you could use the bitwise or/and operations (a single pipe or ampersand too), but you need to be extra careful because that won't work as desired if the operands are not limited to `0` and `1`.

Example of misbehaviour when trying to replace logical with bitwise:

```
2 && 1 == 1
2 & 1  == 0
```

A solution that might work for you is to use some macros and take advantage of the neutral or reversible logical operations to enforce a "boolean" type conversion, then use the bitwise operations:

```
#define OR(A, B)  (!!(A) | !!(B))
#define AND(A, B) (!!(A) & !!(B))
```

About C++ I really don't know the details, but I guess the situation is the same as in C... Maybe you could do some operator overloading black magic serious shit xD.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are doing as best as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the | or & operators? Works in VC++ for common scenerios.

```
#include <iostream>

bool A()
{
    std::cout<<"A";
    return true;
}

bool B()
{
    std::cout<<"B";
    return false;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if(!(B() & A()))
        std::cout<<"Passed one\r\n";
    if(A() | B())
        std::cout<<"Passed two\r\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As pointed out @lasmana, this is indeed a duplicate. The other post has some excellent arguments against using bitwise operators as relates to maintainability and clarity.

Comment: This is dangerous since somebody will come along and correct the code `|` => `||` thinking I made a mistake.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I commented on the maintainability and it definitely answered the question. Using non-shortcut operators in C++ is going to be dangerous no matter how you do it since it strays from normal behavior.

Comment: Don't know, I didn't down-vote.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I've definitely run into that situation a few times. This particular question is from long ago so it doesn't seem like perhaps the one to challenge. However, what does the process look like?